# What are the negatives to using Guava Preconditions with Groovy instead of assert for constraining method arguments?

Tags: groovy, guava

I'm aware that the typical Groovy idiom for checking method preconditions - such as an argument being required to be non-null, or within a certain range of acceptable values - is usually to use `assert`.

However, it seems to me that there are several drawbacks to this approach versus using the familiar (to me anyways) Java approach of relying on the [Preconditions utilities in Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

- If an assertion fails, a `java.lang.AssertionError` is always thrown.  This is far less specific than say, throwing a `NullPointerException` for failed null checks and `IllegalArgumentException` for other argument problems, as can be done easily from `Preconditions`.  If, for whatever reason, I wanted to try-catch a bad method call, the calling code would have a far more difficult time understanding **exactly why** the method failed from an `AssertionError`.
- If I use `assert` for any other sort of checking later in the method - such as validating the state invariants of my class - it will once again be more difficult from the caller to determine the meaning of the `AssertionError` it recieves, versus recieving an `IllegalStateException` or some even more specific custom subtype unique to my application.  Was the failure the caller's fault?  Or is the called class buggy and its internal state messed up?
- It is easier to debug failed `Preconditions` checks - I can set a breakpoint within each of the method calls at the site of the thrown `IllegalArgumentException` or whatever, and know that if it is ever hit.  Alternately I can put breakpoints on whenever *specific* exception types are thrown (i.e., just `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, not any assertion failure) to only catch cases of precondition failures that are currently interesting.
- It is easier for people to **read and interpret** the code later.  A call to `Preconditions` must be a preconditions check, and the specific method called offers even more immediate information.  An `assert` could be checking anything.

About the *only* advantage to using `assert` that I can see is the slight convenience of not having to manually add the printing of the values of the bad arguments as in `constrainWithPreconditions2` below:

```
@Grab(group='com.google.guava', module='guava', version='18.0')
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions

static String constrainWithPreconditions(def param1) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(param1, 'param1 can NOT be null!')
}

static String constrainWithAssertions(def param1) {
    assert param1, 'param1 can NOT be null!'
}

// constrainWithPreconditions(null)
// PRODUCES:
// java.lang.NullPointerException: param1 can NOT be null!

// constrainWithAssertions(null)
// PRODUCES:
// java.lang.AssertionError: param1 can NOT be null!. Expression: param1. Values: param1 = null

static String constrainWithPreconditions2(def param1, def param2) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(param1 < param2, "param1 ($param1) MUST be < param2 ($param2)!")
}

static String constrainWithAssertions2(def param1, def param2) {
    assert param1 < param2, 'param1 MUST be < param2!'
}

 constrainWithPreconditions2(2, 1)
// PRODUCES:
// java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: param1 (2) MUST be < param2 (1)!

// constrainWithAssertions2(2, 1)
// PRODUCES:
// ava.lang.AssertionError: param1 MUST be < param2!. Expression: (param1 < param2). Values: param1 = 2, param2 = 1
```

So what am I missing?  Are there any other drawbacks to `Preconditions`?  Am I missing out on anything else by not using `assert`?

Comment: I prefer Preconditions for the same reasons as mentioned by you.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. No need to use `assert` if `Preconditions` available - good library.

Comment: Assertions and precondition checks are very different things. An assertion is something you believe/expect to always be true in the code; a precondition check is a check that something you have no control over (arguments to your method) conforms to the requirements you have set for how the method can be called.

Comment: @ColinD - I completely agree with that.  Yet the idiom I keep seeing seems to be to use assertions to enforce the precondition checks.  Hence this question.

Comment: IMHO the idiom is pretty wrong. Saving a few strokes weights nothing against the arguments you brought yourself. I'd add to it, that you lose the ability to use asserts for what they were created for, namely possibly time-consuming sanity checks. I use asserts a lot and it's not uncommon to get a 10 times slowdown when they're on. Note also that there's `Verify` in Guava for things which must be always checked and which are no preconditions.

Comment: e.g. C/C++ asserts can be dropped at compilation, no one there puts valueable code there.  just sanity checks (it might not be smart to drop them from production code, but thats another thing). if relevant for the interface/API/..., do proper checks and proper error handling with guava, gcontract, AOP, if/throw, younameit.  use asserts while developing to find the corner cases.  if you forget to put a "proper" check there, the assert is at least there to break early.  groovy's assert is awesome for the developer with the source code in front, but hard to reason for a "user" of your library.